# UITableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths continuously reloads cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a UITableView with a custom cell that contains a UIWebView. I am attempting to reload the cell with the correct height once the webview finishes loading the html content.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    height =  tableView.frame.size.height - tableView.contentSize.height
    return height
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell!
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("bodyFieldCellIdentifier", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    (cell as! SMBodyTableViewCell).frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)
    (cell as! SMBodyTableViewCell).bodyWebView.delegate = self
    (cell as! SMBodyTableViewCell).bodyWebView.loadHTMLString(self.messageBody, baseURL: nil)
    (cell as! SMBodyTableViewCell).bodyWebView.tag = indexPath.row
}
```

In the webViewDidFinishLoad delegate method, I attempt to reload the cell containing the webview.

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(aWebView: UIWebView) {
    let indexPath = NSIndexPath(forRow: aWebView.tag, inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.reloadRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Automatic)
}
```

When I run the app, the cell containing the webview continuously reload. The height seems to be correct and as desired but you can see the cell reloading non-stop. I can't seem to figure out why it continuously reloads. The HTML content I am loading is simple HTML and does not have multiple/endless frames so that webViewDidFinishLoad continuously gets called. I've also tried re-calculating and setting the height of the cell in webViewDidLoad but the height does not seem to be calculated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

when webViewDidFinishLoad you may get height by  webview.scrollView.contentSize.height ,then call reloadRowsAtIndexPaths

Answer (score 0):

Well of course it reloads constantly. That's what you've written it to do.

Each time you load a cell, you trigger the web view inside the cell to load.
When the load completes, it calls `webViewDidFinishLoad`, where you trigger the reload of that same cell. It then calls `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, which triggers the web view to load AGAIN. And on and on.

You should not need the call to `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` in your `webViewDidFinishLoad`. The web view should update it's contents automatically without you having do do anything.